# Установка Yii - framework , переменные среды windows

Tags: php, yii

Пытаюсь установить php -framework Yii но проблема очевидно в установке переменной среды , полный путь до php.exe такой =>

1) C:\WebServers\usr\local\php5

2) Z:\usr\local\php5

вот полный путь в Path =>

....\v1.0\;С:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;Z:\usr\local\php5

устанавливал путь для Path как с диска С так и с диска Z , скажите где я ошибся ?

Comment: Не пользовался фреймоворками, но, смею предположить, что путь нужен от корня веб-сайта, но может и нет. Выложите саму ошибку, что вас заставило считать это ошибкой?

Comment: ошибка такая - php.exe не является внутренней или внешней командой - вот и вся ошибка -

Comment: решено - спасибо

Comment: сделай комментарий ответом -  MAXOPKA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполни в консоли `php-cgi -v`.